# Are Sākta Tantras mentioned/named in any purānas?

Tags: puranas, tantra, agamas, shaktism, agamasastra

From what I have seen It is a Pretty common occurrence to See Vaishnava and Shaiva Puranas mention their respective Agamas by name.

E.g. Varaha Purana mentions Narada Pancharatra and similarly Shiva Purāna mentions Shaiva Agamas such as Kāmika. The Samhita version of the Skanda Purāna also mentions various Shaivagamas such as Vātula, Raurava and so on.

But similarly do Any Puranas mention any Shakta Tantras by name? I would be curious to see any such mention in the Paurānika literature